# How to prevent background image from jumping on transition?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

Is it possible to prevent background image from jumping effect when animation looping?
What i already tried:

- Changing animation type from transition, to position change (left: 0 -> left: -100%)
- Replacing background image to background gradient but result is the same

[DEMO HERE](https://codepen.io/playmadperson/pen/poRLdKE)

```
<button class="loader">
  <span>Loader</span>
</button>
```

```
@keyframes sliding {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}


body {
  padding: 32px;
}

.loader {
  width: 224px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 14px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.loader:after {    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 200%;
    height: 100%;
  background-color: tomato;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg width='210' height='59' viewBox='0 0 210 59' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cmask id='mask0' mask-type='alpha' maskUnits='userSpaceOnUse' x='0' y='0' width='210' height='59'%3E%3Crect width='210' height='59' fill='%23C4C4C4'/%3E%3C/mask%3E%3Cg mask='url(%23mask0)'%3E%3Cg opacity='0.3' filter='url(%23filter0_d)'%3E%3Cpath d='M-42 0H-18L32 59H8L-42 0Z' fill='white'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg opacity='0.3' filter='url(%23filter1_d)'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0H24L74 59H50L0 0Z' fill='white'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg opacity='0.3' filter='url(%23filter2_d)'%3E%3Cpath d='M42 0H66L116 59H92L42 0Z' fill='white'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg opacity='0.3' filter='url(%23filter3_d)'%3E%3Cpath d='M84 0H108L158 59H134L84 0Z' fill='white'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg opacity='0.3' filter='url(%23filter4_d)'%3E%3Cpath d='M126 0H150L200 59H176L126 0Z' fill='white'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cg opacity='0.3' filter='url(%23filter5_d)'%3E%3Cpath d='M168 0H192L242 59H218L168 0Z' fill='white'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3Cfilter id='filter0_d' x='-46' y='-2' width='82' height='67' filterUnits='userSpaceOnUse' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeFlood flood-opacity='0' result='BackgroundImageFix'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix in='SourceAlpha' type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0'/%3E%3CfeOffset dy='2'/%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='2'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.07 0'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in2='BackgroundImageFix' result='effect1_dropShadow'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in='SourceGraphic' in2='effect1_dropShadow' result='shape'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3Cfilter id='filter1_d' x='-4' y='-2' width='82' height='67' filterUnits='userSpaceOnUse' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeFlood flood-opacity='0' result='BackgroundImageFix'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix in='SourceAlpha' type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0'/%3E%3CfeOffset dy='2'/%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='2'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.07 0'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in2='BackgroundImageFix' result='effect1_dropShadow'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in='SourceGraphic' in2='effect1_dropShadow' result='shape'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3Cfilter id='filter2_d' x='38' y='-2' width='82' height='67' filterUnits='userSpaceOnUse' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeFlood flood-opacity='0' result='BackgroundImageFix'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix in='SourceAlpha' type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0'/%3E%3CfeOffset dy='2'/%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='2'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.07 0'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in2='BackgroundImageFix' result='effect1_dropShadow'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in='SourceGraphic' in2='effect1_dropShadow' result='shape'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3Cfilter id='filter3_d' x='80' y='-2' width='82' height='67' filterUnits='userSpaceOnUse' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeFlood flood-opacity='0' result='BackgroundImageFix'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix in='SourceAlpha' type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0'/%3E%3CfeOffset dy='2'/%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='2'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.07 0'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in2='BackgroundImageFix' result='effect1_dropShadow'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in='SourceGraphic' in2='effect1_dropShadow' result='shape'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3Cfilter id='filter4_d' x='122' y='-2' width='82' height='67' filterUnits='userSpaceOnUse' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeFlood flood-opacity='0' result='BackgroundImageFix'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix in='SourceAlpha' type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0'/%3E%3CfeOffset dy='2'/%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='2'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.07 0'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in2='BackgroundImageFix' result='effect1_dropShadow'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in='SourceGraphic' in2='effect1_dropShadow' result='shape'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3Cfilter id='filter5_d' x='164' y='-2' width='82' height='67' filterUnits='userSpaceOnUse' color-interpolation-filters='sRGB'%3E%3CfeFlood flood-opacity='0' result='BackgroundImageFix'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix in='SourceAlpha' type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 127 0'/%3E%3CfeOffset dy='2'/%3E%3CfeGaussianBlur stdDeviation='2'/%3E%3CfeColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0.07 0'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in2='BackgroundImageFix' result='effect1_dropShadow'/%3E%3CfeBlend mode='normal' in='SourceGraphic' in2='effect1_dropShadow' result='shape'/%3E%3C/filter%3E%3C/defs%3E%3C/svg%3E%0A");
    color: white;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    animation: sliding 1.75s linear infinite;
    will-change: transform;
  }
.loader span {
  line-height: 20px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the background is repeated we can have this animation definition and can control the speed of the animation by setting 60-120s as per your requirement for the animation property.

```
@keyframes sliding {
  from {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
/*use negative width if you want it to flow right to left else and positive for left to right*/
  to {
    background-position: -10000px 0;
  }
}
```